# Failed to save '.env' file: Unable to write file

Tags: filesystem, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to save changes to a file in VSCode but suddenly getting this error-

[image]

The project folder is located in `Local Disk` partition on my hard disk, and it is mounted on startup as can be seen-

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

**Edit 1:-**
Here's the list of commands that @heynnema asked to run-

[image]
[image]

[image]

I also tried the command `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4` after booting from live usb, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't support Zorin OS here. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All of your partitions are marked as "Microsoft basic data" which would be incorrect for a Ubuntu file system. I don't know what to fsck.

Answer (score 1):

Your local disk/partition has a file system problem, and has become read-only.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I still get the same error in vscode after trying the solution above. :(

Comment: @SapinderSingh  Edit your question and show me the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo fdisk -l` and tell me the exact fsck command that you gave. What is the small icon that appears on the Local Disk folder?

Comment: I've provided the outputs in the question. And that icon is the same for all disks on my system. (I'm on zorin os to be specific, which is ubuntu-based.)